# Generate list of N quarters of year(s) relative to the date in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I generate a list of N future quarters of the year(s) relative to the current date? The first quarter generated should be the next quarter from the current. Notably, the quarter must wrap-around and the year must increment at the end of each year.

For example, with an output format of `Qn-YY` on September 2024 the next 3 quarters would be `["Q4-24", "Q1-25", "Q2-25"]`.

Comment: Please show us your code so far

Comment: Solution working so far based on the suggested solution
`start_year = dt.datetime.today().year
start_quarter =(dt.datetime.today().month-1)//3+1
total_quarters = 11
future_quarters = [f"Q{i % 4 + 1}-{start_year + (i // 4)}" for i in range(start_quarter, start_quarter+total_quarters)]
`
Problem with code solved, problem with stackoverflow.com requires solution

Comment: If you want to ask how to improve your question, ask on [meta].

Comment: @JanisE, in the review queue, are canned messages, not all of them are helpful.  In general, a question requires an explanation of the problem, your attempted code, expected output and actual output.  As it stands, the question is of no use to future visitors.

Comment: @RohitGupta "your attempted code, ... and actual output" that only applies to debugging questions. This isn't one.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I did say in general.  And I still think the OP should post their attempt at coding so far.  Otherwise, we could be doing someone's assignment.  And they have posted the code as a comment !  And I was trying to be helpful.

Comment: @RohitGupta "*I still think the OP should post their attempt at coding so far*" you think wrong. "How to" questions are perfectly acceptable. Moreover, they are some of the most well known and highest scored questions on the site. Your claim that code is needed simply does not align with the goal of the site, nor its history.

Comment: @VLAZ indeed OP *should* (but definitely not *required to*) post their effort, otherwise most will consider it "does not show any research effort" and vote accordingly and as result OP will have to wait till enough people having the same problem upvote later.

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424508/how-can-i-improve-my-question-to-remove-question-ban).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use list comprehension:

```py
start_quarter = 1
start_year = 23
total_quarters = 10

future_quarters = [f"Q{i % 4 + 1}-{start_year + (i // 4)}" for i in range(start_quarter, total_quarters)]

print(future_quarters)
```

Output:

```py
['Q2-23', 'Q3-23', 'Q4-23', 'Q1-24', 'Q2-24', 'Q3-24', 'Q4-24', 'Q1-25', 'Q2-25', 'Q3-25']
```

Rationale: the quarters need to start from one quarter after the initial one, but modulo 4 gives us the numbers 0 to 3. This nicely works out when just adding 1 to the value after modulo. The year should increment after four quarters, and integer division by 4 gives us that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas period series creating with `period_range` giving a start date and number of periods with a frequency.

```
p = pd.period_range('2020-01-01', periods=12, freq='Q')
ps = p.strftime('Q%q-%y')
ps
```

Output:

```
Index(['Q1-20', 'Q2-20', 'Q3-20', 'Q4-20', 'Q1-21', 'Q2-21', 'Q3-21', 'Q4-21',
       'Q1-22', 'Q2-22', 'Q3-22', 'Q4-22'],
      dtype='object')
```

and

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Quater'] = ps
```

Output:

```
   Quarter
0    Q1-20
1    Q2-20
2    Q3-20
3    Q4-20
4    Q1-21
5    Q2-21
6    Q3-21
7    Q4-21
8    Q1-22
9    Q2-22
10   Q3-22
11   Q4-22
```

And, since this is using a real period dtype, you can get the start and end of the quarters:

```
df['Period Start'] = p.start_time
df['Period End'] = p.end_time.normalize()
```

Output:

```
   Quarter Period End Period Start
0    Q1-20 2020-03-31   2020-01-01
1    Q2-20 2020-06-30   2020-04-01
2    Q3-20 2020-09-30   2020-07-01
3    Q4-20 2020-12-31   2020-10-01
4    Q1-21 2021-03-31   2021-01-01
5    Q2-21 2021-06-30   2021-04-01
6    Q3-21 2021-09-30   2021-07-01
7    Q4-21 2021-12-31   2021-10-01
8    Q1-22 2022-03-31   2022-01-01
9    Q2-22 2022-06-30   2022-04-01
10   Q3-22 2022-09-30   2022-07-01
11   Q4-22 2022-12-31   2022-10-01
```